# Length is invariant under parameterization

Tags: metric-spaces, metric-geometry

I'm reading the book [*A Course in Metric Geometry*](https://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/akp-papers/bbi.pdf) by Dmitri Burago, Yuri Burago Sergei Ivanov. In page 45 it says "it is easy to see that all parametrization of a curve have equal length", but I do not understand why this is true.

> **2.1.1.** **Definition of length structures.**
>
> A length structure on a topological space $ X $ is a class $ A $ of admissible
>   paths, which is a subset of all continuous paths in $ X $, together with a map
>   $ L : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup \{\infty \} $; the map is called length of path. The class $ A $ has to satisfy the following assumptions **:**
>
> $(1)$ The class $ A $ is closed under restrictions **:** if $ \gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow X $ is an admissible path and $ a \leq c \leq d \leq b$, then the restriction of $ \gamma $ to $ [c, d] $ is also admissible.
>
> (2) $ A $ is closed under concatenations (products) of paths. Namely, if a
>   path $ \gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow X $ is such that its restrictions $ \gamma_1, \gamma_2 $ to $ [a, c] $ and $ [c, b] $ are both admissible paths, then so is $\gamma $.
>
> $(3)$ $ A $ is closed under (at least) linear reparameterizations **:** for an
>   admissible path $ \gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow X $ and a homeomorphism $ \phi : [c, d] \rightarrow [a, b] $ of the form $ \phi(t) = \alpha t + \beta $, the composition $ \gamma \circ \phi(t) $ is also an admissible path.
>
> We require that $ L $ possesses the following properties **:**
>
> $(1)$ Length of paths is additive **:** $ L(\gamma {\big|}_{[a,b]}) = L(\gamma {\big|}_{[a,c]}) + L(\gamma{\big|}_{[c,b]}) $ for any $c \in [a, b] $.
>
> $(2)$ The length of a piece of a path continuously depends on the piece.
>   More formally, for a path $ \gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow X $ of finite length, denote by $ L(\gamma, a, t) $ the length of the restriction of $ \gamma : [a, b] \rightarrow X $ to the segment $ [a, t] $. We require that $ L(γ, a, \cdot) $ be a continuous function.
>
> $(3)$ The length is invariant under reparameterizations **:** $ L(\gamma \circ \phi) = L(\gamma) $ for a linear homeomorphism $\phi$.
>
> $(4)$ We require length structures to agree with the topology of $X$ in the
>   following sense **:** for a neighborhood $U_x$ of a point $x$, the length of
>   paths connecting $x$ with points of the complement of $U_x$ is separated
>   from zero **:** $$ \inf \{ L(\gamma) : \gamma(a) = x, \gamma(b) \in X \setminus U_x \} > 0.$$

$ \qquad $

> **Definition 2.5.1.** An (unparameterized) curve is an equivalence class of
>   the minimal equivalence relation satisfying the following **:** paths $ \gamma_1 : I_1 \rightarrow X $ and $ \gamma_2 : I_2 \rightarrow X $ are equivalent whenever there exists a nondecreasing continuous map $ \phi $ from $ I_1 $ onto $ I_2 $ such that $ \gamma_1 = \gamma_2 \circ \phi $.
>
> Paths (representatives of an equivalence class) are also called parameterizations of the curve and re-parameterizations of one another.

$ \qquad $

I need to prove that $ L(\gamma) = L(\gamma \circ \phi) $ where $ \gamma : I \rightarrow X $ is a path and $ \phi : I' \rightarrow I $ is a nondecreasing continuous map, I think I should use broken line to approximate $ \phi $, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could you give more hint? My thought is that I can approximate $ \phi $ by piecewise linear function $ \sigma $ (by the uniformly continuity of $ \phi $) and I hope $ L(\gamma) = L(\gamma \circ \sigma) $ will get close to $ L(\gamma \circ \phi) $.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But I used the definition (1), (2), (3) of $ L $ in my above approach.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. I found their discussion of rectifiable curves, and thought that was their definition of length (it is commonly is), and that you had gotten this from somewhere else, but I looked again and found the definitions you've quoted. From the more traditional treatment of length, this is easy enough to prove, but I am not familiar with "Length structures".